# Can I declare a typed property so that it accepts a null value as well?

Tags: php, types, type-hinting

Why do I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Typed property $description must be string, null used

when I try to assign `null` to a typed property? Like this:

```php
new Foo(null);
```

```php
class Foo
{
  private string $description;

  public function __construct($description)
  {
    $this->description = $description; // <-- Error on this line
  }
}
```

Comment: You typedef'd it as string. If you don't pass anything into the constructor, then it will fail.

Comment: [Didn't you kind of ask this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60838396/1415724)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no completely different question. I want to have it be a string, but also allow null. In Java you can pass in null for String types.

Comment: @Catfish alrighty.

Comment: Looks like PHP provides optional types via `?`. `private ?string $description` allows me to pass in a string or null. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHP has support for [nullable types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullable_types) since [PHP 7.1](https://www.php.net/releases/7_1_0.php).

If you want to declare a property to be able to hold both a specific type or `null`, you prepend `?` to the type declaration.

Using your example:

```
class Foo
{
  private ?string $description;

  public function __construct(?string $description)
  {
    $this->description = $description;
  }
}
```

Comment: ahh.. the other size of the variable type to c#